# format bootstrap nav links css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

```
<header role="banner" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-toggle="collapse-side" data-target=".side-collapse" data-target-2=".side-collapse-container" type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-inverse side-collapse in">
      <nav role="navigation" class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#Home">Home</li>
          <li><a href="#users">Users</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Places</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I need to format the li links but no matter what I try I get no result. I'm new to css and bootstrap so any help would be wonderful and gratefully received

```
/* unvisited link */
nav navbar-nav a:link {
color: red;
}

/* visited link */
nav navbar-nav a:visited {
color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
nav navbar-nav a:hover {
color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
nav navbar-nav  a:active {
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the `<a>`

```
.nav li a {
  color : red;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it didn't work. I must be missing something. Very frustrating. Thanks again.

Comment: I tried it in a jsfiddle and it works

https://jsfiddle.net/nu65mu4s/

The issue is this `nav navbar-nav`

it should be like this `.nav.navbar-nav`, because both classes are on same element

What you wrote previously meant `navbar-nav` is a child of `nav` that's why it was not working. 

Please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The nav navbar-nav are CSS class selectors. So they must be in denoted with a '.' infront while applying CSS. Your code must look like this:

```
    /* unvisited link */
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: red;
    }
```

You can edit the rest of your CSS likewise.